# Participant list after zoom session?

Tags: mailing-list, zoom.us

I recently hosted (zoom pro) a surprise zoom meeting for a friend’s 80th birthday. I enabled all recording options (speaker, gallery, shared, audio, etc). During the meeting, I admitted over fifty folks.

After the meeting, I looked into getting the list of participants, but was surprised that the list came back empty.

I didn’t require registration to join.

Am I out of luck on this? Or, is there a way to get this list?

Yikes!

Answer (score 1):

From your Zoom profile page, click on `Reports`, then click on `Usage`. Adjust the date range at the top of the page such that you can get to the meeting that you wish to download participants information from.

For the meeting that you are interested in, there should be a row that appears at the bottom within the table. On the right side, there is a clickable number that represents the number of participants for that meeting. Click on that number and you will be given the option to download the participants list *(shown in the following picture)*.

[image: Example of participants list]